# '-mmacosx-version-min' not allowed with '-miphoneos-version-min'

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, clang, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile lib for iOS simulator:

```
export CC="clang -arch i386 -mios-version-min=5.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk"

export CXX="clang++ -arch i386 -mios-version-min=5.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk"

../configure --prefix=/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/libadx_installed --enable-optimized --disable-assertions

unset CC CXX

make VERBOSE=1 -j4
```

and i'm getting error:

```
clang: error: invalid argument '-mmacosx-version-min=10.9' not allowed with '-miphoneos-version-min=5.0'
```

since i'm compiling for ios i'm using `-miphoneos-version-min` parameter and `-mmacosx-version-min=10.9` is added automatically somehow.

How can i fix it?

UPDATE: make VERBOSE=1

```
llvm[3]: Linking Release Loadable Module LLVMHello.dylib
clang++  -O3 -rdynamic -Wl,-rpath -Wl,@executable_path/../lib -L/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/llvm_34_build_i386/Release/lib -L/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/llvm_34_build_i386/Release/lib -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -stdlib=libc++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -stdlib=libc++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -stdlib=libc++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -stdlib=libc++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -stdlib=libc++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -stdlib=libc++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -stdlib=libc++ -m32  -Wl,-flat_namespace -Wl,-undefined,suppress -dynamiclib -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -o /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/llvm_34_build_i386/Release/lib/LLVMHello.dylib /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/llvm_34_build_i386/lib/Transforms/Hello/Release/Hello.o \
       -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/llvm_34_build_i386/lib/Transforms/Hello/Release/Hello.exports.sed -lz -lpthread -lcurses -lm 
clang: error: invalid argument '-mmacosx-version-min=10.9' not allowed with '-miphoneos-version-min=5.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was error in lib's Makefile, fixed by removing lines containing 'mmacosx-version-min'. By default it adds 'mmacosx-version-min' for non-ARM builds for some reason